# ng-focus and ng-blur on ios and android cordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova-3

I have created a cordova-angular app which is using less-1.5.0.min.js for generating css files, now i am trying to add ng-focus and ng-blur on anchor tags its not working in cordova 3.3.if i add it in button element it works fine.
I am trying to hide the drop down menu when i click outside the menu button/anchor tag.

the anchor element:

```
     <a href="#" ng-blur = "toggle('menu')" class="fa fa-bars"   ng-focus="toggle('menu')" ></a>
```

Button element:

```
     <button ng-blur = "toggle('menu')"   ng-focus="toggle('menu')"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-click instead of ng-blur or ng-focus. To use ng-click without the 300ms tap delay on a mobile app using Cordova, make sure to include the ngTouch module in your app, as such:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch']);
```

Then just use ng-click and it should trigger without any problem. Also make sure that your function **toggle** is within the same scope that your element is in.

```
<a href="#" ng-click="toggle('menu')"></a>
```

Hope this helps.